# Is there a good "free" graphical web.config editor?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config

Like:

https://www.hunterstone.com/hsstore/ProductDetails.aspx?productID=101

but free :-)

Comment: Does "free" equal mostly free or really free?  I guess I'm asking what's with the quotes.

Comment: the quotes mean free, or almost free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good part of the web.config can now be edited directly with IIS7.

It's kind of free as it comes with Windows 7 and 2003.

Answer (score 5):

I use ASPhere. It's great!

> About ASPhere ...
>
> ASPhere is a freeware utility
>   primarily intended for creating and
>   modifying configuration files for
>   ASP.NET. But they are not only
>   web.config files ASPhere can work
>   with, you can use it for viewing and
>   editing normal XML files and plain
>   text files as well.

http://www.asphere.cz/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Express?](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/)

More seriously... your friend [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=web.config+editor+free)

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for.. but I guess the answer is implicit: there is none (or it's not worth going that route if we can edit them with VS). Thanks.